# Show that the Laplacian on these domains is isospectral

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, sp.spectral-theory, laplacian, semigroups-of-operators

Let $\Omega_i\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be bounded and open, $A_i$ denote the weak Laplacian with domain $\mathcal D(A):=\{u\in H_0^1(\Omega_i):\Delta u\in L^2(\Omega_i)\}$ on $L^2(\Omega_i)$ and $$T_i(t)f:=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}e^{-\lambda^{i}_nt}\langle f,e_n^{i}\rangle_{L^2(\Omega_i)}e^{i}\;\;\;\text{for }f\in L^2(\Omega_i)\text{ and }t\ge0,$$ where $(e^i_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $(\lambda^{i}_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ are the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $-A_i$, respectively.

> We know that $(T_i(t))_{t\ge0}$ is a strongly continuous contraction semigroup on $L^2(\Omega_i)$ with generator $A_i$. In [this paper](https://application.wiley-vch.de/books/sample/3527408304_c01.pdf#page=64) it is claimed below equation 1.131 on p. 64 that if $U:L^2(\Omega_1)\to L^2(\Omega_2)$ satisfies $$\forall t>0:UT_1(t)=T_2(t)U\tag1,$$ then "$\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ are isospectral", which I guess means that $\lambda^1_n=\lambda^2_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.
>
> How can we show that?

Comment: Well, if two operators are similar, they have the same eigenvalues. That's standard linear algebra, isn't it?

Comment: By the way, one should probably add that the linear operator $U$ in your question is bijective (in the paper you linked, it is even assumed to be a unitary).

Comment: @JochenGlueck Thank you for your comment. How do you define "similar" for operators and why does it follow from $(1)$ that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are similar?

Comment: An operator $S_1$ on a Banach space $X_1$ is called similar to an operator $S_2$ on a Banach space $X_2$ iff there exists a continuous linear bijection $V: X_1 \to X_2$ such that $S_1 = V^{-1}S_2V$ (i.e., it's just the same as for matrices). In your situation, for instance the operators $T_1(1)$ and $T_2(1)$ are similar, and so they have the same eigenvalues. Hence, it follows from the spectral mapping theorem for the point spectrum that the generators $A_1$ and $A_2$ have the same eigenvalues, too (one has to be a bit careful about multiplicities here, but the details work out well).

Comment: Alternatively, one can argue directly via the generators (which is probably a bit clearer since it avoids the spectral mapping theorem): an unbounded operator $A_1$ on $X_1$ is said to be similar to an unbounded operator $A_2$ on $X_2$ iff there exists a a continuous linear bijection $V: X_1 \to X_2$ such that $V \mathcal{D}(A_1) = \mathcal{D}(A_2)$ and $A_1 = V^{-1} A_2 V$. In your situation, it follows immediately from (1) and from the definition of the generator of a $C_0$-semigroup that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are similar.

Comment: @JochenGlueck Thank you. Using the generators, it is really trivial. And I think we don't need the unitary assumption; $U$ can be any bijective bounded linear operator between Banach spaces.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, a bounded linear bijection suffices. (Indeed, in the paper you link the result is also formulated for bijections rather than uniteries, three lines after equation (1.131); unitaries are mentioned a few lines earlier, but for different reasons).

Comment: @JochenGlueck Just one addition: I've read that if there is an Euclidean isometry $\iota$ between $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$, then they are isospectral. I guess the unitary operator to be consider then is $Uf:=f\circ\iota^{-1}$ for $f\in L^2(\Omega_1)$. Why does this $U$ satisfy $(1)$?

Comment: @JochenGlueck And if it does satisfy $(1)$, I wonder why the same doesn't apply in way more generality: It seems like that if $X,Y$ are any Hilbert spaces with orthnormal bases $(e_i)_{i\in I},(f_i)_{i\in I}$ (common index set $I$), then we can *always* find an unitary $U$ with $Ue_i=f_i$. This simply follows from the fact that $V:X\to\ell^2(I),x\mapsto(\langle x,e_i\rangle)_{i\in I}$ and $W:Y\to\ell^2(I),y\mapsto(\langle y,f_i\rangle)_{i\in I}$ are unitary isomorphisms so that we can take $U:=W^{-1}\circ V$. Since this is way too general, there must be something I'm missing.

Comment: Concerning you first comment: Yes, that's precisely the $U$ you would like to use. Equality (1) then follows from the fact that every isometry in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is a composition of a translation and a rotation, and that the (distributional) Laplace operator commutes with translations and rotations. Concerning your second comment: Your argument proves that two Hilbert spaces of the same dimension are isomorphic; but in order to have (1) you would need that the $e_i$ and $f_i$ are eigenvectors of your operators for the same eigenvalues.

Comment: @JochenGlueck Please take a look at the separate question I've asked for that: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4034335/47771.

Comment: Thanks for your comment; I'll right an answer there.

Comment: @JochenGlueck I wasn't aware of this characterization of isometries on $\mathbb R^d$ (do you have a reference at hand?), but even with that wouldn't we somehow need to get rid of the second orthonormal basis $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ (in the other question) and subsitute it with the orthonormal basis given by $(Ue_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$?

Comment: @JochenGlueck Thank you in advance for your effort.